# Removing the subsequent words after identified key words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I am trying out regular expressions and would like to find out if there is any way to remove immediate subsequent words after the word I have identified.

For example,

```
text = "This is the full sentence that I wish to apply regex on."
```

If I want to remove the word "full", I understand that I can do the following:

```
result = re.sub(r"full", "", text)
```

which would give me

```
This is the sentence that I wish to apply regex on.
```

Is there any way to get the following statement from my above text? (e.g. keep parts 5 words after the word "full" or remove the first 5 words after "full" )

```
apply regex on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match everything from the beginning to the string to the `full`, then repeat a group of `\s\S+` 5 times to match 5 words, and replace the whole match with the empty string:

```
^.*?full(?:\s\S+){5}\s
```

https://regex101.com/r/H6tdCH/1